# How to print following json data using foreach in php

Tags: php, json

```
[
    "1",
    "FIR 1",
    "3",
    "FIR 2",
    {
        "name": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, rebum porro usu ex. Ne periculis eloquentiam per, appareat facilisi evertitur ex duo, eum in prima suavitate signiferumque. Mel pertinax voluptatum et. Eos brute phaedrum repudiare in, an mea graece graeci quaestio. Nec cu percipit praesent, dicit percipitur eu eam. Id quis splendide est, ut audire adolescens pro, vis consul fabulas expetenda ut. Graecis nusquam sea et. Sumo suavitate est ei, cu diam convenire mei, pro possim eligendi officiis ut. Delenit theophrastus eum ad,"
    },
    {
        "name": "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, rebum porro usu ex. Ne periculis eloquentiam per, appareat facilisi evertitur ex duo, eum in prima suavitate signiferumque. Mel pertinax voluptatum et. Eos brute phaedrum repudiare in, an mea graece graeci quaestio. Nec cu percipit praesent, dicit percipitur eu eam. Id quis splendide est, ut audire adolescens pro, vis consul fabulas expetenda ut. Graecis nusquam sea et. Sumo suavitate est ei, cu diam convenire mei, pro possim eligendi officiis ut. Delenit theophrastus eum ad,"
    },
    "4",
    "FIR 3",
    {
        "name": "ccccccccccc",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, rebum porro usu ex. Ne periculis eloquentiam per, appareat facilisi evertitur ex duo, eum in prima suavitate signiferumque. Mel pertinax voluptatum et. Eos brute phaedrum repudiare in, an mea graece graeci quaestio. Nec cu percipit praesent, dicit percipitur eu eam. Id quis splendide est, ut audire adolescens pro, vis consul fabulas expetenda ut. Graecis nusquam sea et. Sumo suavitate est ei, cu diam convenire mei, pro possim eligendi officiis ut. Delenit theophrastus eum ad,"
    },
    {
        "name": "dddddddddd",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, rebum porro usu ex. Ne periculis eloquentiam per, appareat facilisi evertitur ex duo, eum in prima suavitate signiferumque. Mel pertinax voluptatum et. Eos brute phaedrum repudiare in, an mea graece graeci quaestio. Nec cu percipit praesent, dicit percipitur eu eam. Id quis splendide est, ut audire adolescens pro, vis consul fabulas expetenda ut. Graecis nusquam sea et. Sumo suavitate est ei, cu diam convenire mei, pro possim eligendi officiis ut. Delenit theophrastus eum ad,"
    },
    "5",
    "FIR 4",
    "6",
    "FIR 5",
    {
        "name": "eeeeeeeeeeeee",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, rebum porro usu ex. Ne periculis eloquentiam per, appareat facilisi evertitur ex duo, eum in prima suavitate signiferumque. Mel pertinax voluptatum et. Eos brute phaedrum repudiare in, an mea graece graeci quaestio. Nec cu percipit praesent, dicit percipitur eu eam. Id quis splendide est, ut audire adolescens pro, vis consul fabulas expetenda ut. Graecis nusquam sea et. Sumo suavitate est ei, cu diam convenire mei, pro possim eligendi officiis ut. Delenit theophrastus eum ad,"
    }
]
```

Comment: Read [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Just print the json or decode the json and print it out?

Comment: i tried using foreach loop like foreach($data as $values=>$key) bt its not working. Also tried  foreach($data as $values). But both are giving PHP warning : Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: check https://3v4l.org/QbG9p

Comment: @Saty : I want to print this result using foreach loop

Comment: @Gauri, Is my solution work for you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$json = '[ "1", "FIR 1", "3", "FIR 2", { "name": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, rebum porro usu ex. Ne periculis eloquentiam per, appareat facilisi evertitur ex duo, eum in prima suavitate signiferumque. Mel pertinax voluptatum et. Eos brute phaedrum repudiare in, an mea graece graeci quaestio. Nec cu percipit praesent, dicit percipitur eu eam. Id quis splendide est, ut audire adolescens pro, vis consul fabulas expetenda ut. Graecis nusquam sea et. Sumo suavitate est ei, cu diam convenire mei, pro possim eligendi officiis ut. Delenit theophrastus eum ad," }, { "name": "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb", "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, rebum porro usu ex. Ne periculis eloquentiam per, appareat facilisi evertitur ex duo, eum in prima suavitate signiferumque. Mel pertinax voluptatum et. Eos brute phaedrum repudiare in, an mea graece graeci quaestio. Nec cu percipit praesent, dicit percipitur eu eam. Id quis splendide est, ut audire adolescens pro, vis consul fabulas expetenda ut. Graecis nusquam sea et. Sumo suavitate est ei, cu diam convenire mei, pro possim eligendi officiis ut. Delenit theophrastus eum ad," }, "4", "FIR 3", { "name": "ccccccccccc", "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, rebum porro usu ex. Ne periculis eloquentiam per, appareat facilisi evertitur ex duo, eum in prima suavitate signiferumque. Mel pertinax voluptatum et. Eos brute phaedrum repudiare in, an mea graece graeci quaestio. Nec cu percipit praesent, dicit percipitur eu eam. Id quis splendide est, ut audire adolescens pro, vis consul fabulas expetenda ut. Graecis nusquam sea et. Sumo suavitate est ei, cu diam convenire mei, pro possim eligendi officiis ut. Delenit theophrastus eum ad," }, { "name": "dddddddddd", "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, rebum porro usu ex. Ne periculis eloquentiam per, appareat facilisi evertitur ex duo, eum in prima suavitate signiferumque. Mel pertinax voluptatum et. Eos brute phaedrum repudiare in, an mea graece graeci quaestio. Nec cu percipit praesent, dicit percipitur eu eam. Id quis splendide est, ut audire adolescens pro, vis consul fabulas expetenda ut. Graecis nusquam sea et. Sumo suavitate est ei, cu diam convenire mei, pro possim eligendi officiis ut. Delenit theophrastus eum ad," }, "5", "FIR 4", "6", "FIR 5", { "name": "eeeeeeeeeeeee", "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, rebum porro usu ex. Ne periculis eloquentiam per, appareat facilisi evertitur ex duo, eum in prima suavitate signiferumque. Mel pertinax voluptatum et. Eos brute phaedrum repudiare in, an mea graece graeci quaestio. Nec cu percipit praesent, dicit percipitur eu eam. Id quis splendide est, ut audire adolescens pro, vis consul fabulas expetenda ut. Graecis nusquam sea et. Sumo suavitate est ei, cu diam convenire mei, pro possim eligendi officiis ut. Delenit theophrastus eum ad," } ]';

$datas = json_decode($json);
```

Decode json and add it to print_object function will print all data.

```
print_object($datas);   //Here $datas should be decoded Json with json_decode() 

function print_object($datas) {
    foreach ($datas as $data) {

        if (is_object($data)) {
            print_object($data);
        } else {
            echo $data . '<br>';
            ;
        }
    }
}
```

Would you please try this ?

Comment: @Gaurideshmukh Do you get an error? For me it's working.

Comment: @Gaurideshmukh Did you take a look at the server's error log. Probably you can find something there.

But without any additional code I can't debug it better.

Comment: @MaulikKanani: thankx. but i still not getting any output. Its Just showing blank page

Comment: @Gaurideshmukh I think you have another mistake in your code.

Comment: @M4R1KU - This is what i am getting error: Call to undefined function print_object()

Comment: @MaulikKanani : 1
FIR 1
3
FIR 2
4
FIR 3
5
FIR 4
6
FIR 5   Only this data is getting me

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a JSON String. You need to decode it first to ready it as array/objects. [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function in PHP converts your JSON String to array/objects. Like this,

```
$array=json_decode($JSON_STRING,true);
```

Second argument in **json_decode** denotes that you want to get the output as Array instead of object which is default return value.

Now traverse through **decoded JSON** like this,

```
forach($array as $value) {
     echo $value;
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

Store your json string in a variable and put it through `json_decode` and you can then do a foreach loop on the valid object.

```
$json = json_decode($jsonText, true); #Edit made here, json_decode($jsonText, true)
foreach( $json as $key => $value) 
{
    echo "Key: ". $key .", Value: ". $value;
}
```

Comment: Hey, i tried this but it giving me PHP Recoverable Error – 

Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Comment: hi there, sorry that it didn't help with your problem.  I forgot to add the `boolean` to make it an associated array when decoding the jsonstring.  without the boolean true, the json is a bunch of objects which would through that particular error.  try again with the edit i made to the answer.